# How can I declare a method then define it later?

Tags: c#, class

In C# is there a way to declare the class then define it later?   I really like in C++ where I can list all the methods at the top like a TOC then define everything later.

Can that be done is C#?

I have used the idea of defining a method that just runs a similarly named method in it then the similar method is at the bottom.   but I am thinking there is a better way and googling returns a bunch of basic code on creating classes with no answer.

so here is what I do...

```
...
public void methodA(){methodAcontent()};
public void methodB()...etc...

...further down...

private void methodAcontent(){
...All the code..
}
```

is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this like `Interface` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b.aspx

Comment: Ha!  Duh, I should have realized that.  Thanks!

Comment: Interfaces assume an abstraction.  Declaring your "api" at the top of the class is meant for skimmable/readable code.

Answer (score 0):

- Or this an [Abstract class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/sf985hc5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) with `abstract` methods.

Comment: abstract class exist in c++, it's different things

Comment: presence of it in `C++` doesn't eliminate it's presence and meaning in `C#`. Which is "similiar" on what is OP's asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need that?

C# is using multipass compilation, so it doesn't matter where the function is defined and when used. You can have function defined at end of the class and use it in the beginning and it will still compile fine.

Also IDE helps you with that. You have ability to collapse bodies of all methods, there is list of all methods in one combobox and InteliSense is extremly helpful in finding correct methods.

And using practices from C++ in C# is really bad idea, because both are quite different in how they solve the problems.

Comment: When I glance at a c# class, I would like to just see its public api without seeing the details.  I also don't want to be bound to an editor like visual studio to be smart and provide this for me, e.g. `less MyClass.cs' should output skimmable code.  In javascript this is possible due to function hoisting.

Answer (score 0):

There's not a good way to do this in the C# language, but the Visual Studio IDE can collapse a file to its definitions which you can then expand individually (see [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/03/18/collapse-to-definitions-with-outlining-vstipedit0032.aspx)). This along with [code regions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a1ybwek%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) helps me organize longer files.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this as a means to "document" the public interface to a class that's properly encapsulating a concept or object in your problem domain, then use an interface.

If you're doing it as a means to get an "overview" the structure of a class, then Visual Studio has several ways to give you this. You can collapse the code to just its definitions (Ctrl+M, O), or look at the Class View (Ctrl+W, C).